# Iterating over a sorted array and storing the count of distinct integers

Tags: java

Can somebody PLEASE answer my specific question, I cannot use material not covered in class yet and must do it this way.

I'm trying to iterate over a sorted array and if the previous number == the current number it stores the count in possiton n of a new array; when the previous number != the current number, it then moves to n+1 on the new array and starts counting again.

I'm debugging it now but having trouble working out what it isn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    // Get the count of instances.
    int[] countOfNumbers = new int[50];         // Array to store count
    int sizeOfArray = 0;                        // Last position of array filled
    int instanceCounter = 1;                    // Counts number of instances
    int previousNumber = 0;                     // Number stored at [k-1]

    for (int k=1; k < finalArrayOfNumbers.length; k++) {
        previousNumber = finalArrayOfNumbers[k-0];

        if (previousNumber == finalArrayOfNumbers[k]) {

            instanceCounter++;
            countOfNumbers[sizeOfArray] = instanceCounter;

        }

        instanceCounter = 1; 
        sizeOfArray++;
        countOfNumbers[sizeOfArray] = instanceCounter;
```

Don't worry about mapping or anything, I just need to know how If I have an array of:

[20, 20, 40, 40, 50]

I can get back

[2, 2, 1]

Comment: 1) `countOfNumbers` should be at least size of `finalArrayOfNumbers.length` 2) `previousNumber == finalArrayOfNumbers[k]` is always true

Comment: Can you explain how your point in (2) is always true? I'm not seeing it, thanks Denis.

Comment: you assign it first `previousNumber = finalArrayOfNumbers[k-0]` and then on the next line compare to the same value `previousNumber == finalArrayOfNumbers[k]`.

Comment: I may be a bit confused at your question.  What if the input array is [20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 40, 40, 50]?  What would the expected output be?

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of neat tools in the Java API so you can avoid doing a lot of this yourself:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(20, 20, 40, 40, 50);
    Map<Integer, Integer> freq = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i: list) {
        freq.put(i, Collections.frequency(list, i));
    }
    System.out.println(freq.values());
```

That'll print `[2, 2, 1]` like you wanted.

Alternatively if you'd like a list of only the distinct values in the list, you can use an implementation of Set.

But since you're restricted because this is a class assignment, you could do something like this instead:

```
    int[] a = { 20, 20, 40, 40, 50 };
    int[] freq = new int[a.length];
    // count frequencies
    for (int i = 1, j = 0, count = 1; i <= a.length; i++, count++) {
        if (i == a.length || a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
            freq[j++] = count;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    // print
    for (int i = 0; i < freq.length && freq[i] != 0; i++) {
        System.out.println(freq[i]);
    }
```

And the output is still the same.

I put comments in the two places you were off, here's your fixed code.

```
    for (int k = 1; k < finalArrayOfNumbers.length; k++) {
        previousNumber = finalArrayOfNumbers[k - 1]; // changed 0 to 1
        if (previousNumber == finalArrayOfNumbers[k]) {
            instanceCounter++;
            countOfNumbers[sizeOfArray] = instanceCounter;
        } else { // put this last bit in an else block
            instanceCounter = 1;
            sizeOfArray++;
            countOfNumbers[sizeOfArray] = instanceCounter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Providing the OP with fixed code will NOT help him learn how to program.  He needs to work it out for himself ...

Comment: @StephenC He was close and he attempted to solve the problem, which is a lot more than some can say. Sometimes we learn best by example, and can read through our code to understand our mistakes. Plus I've given some other advice. If the OP still doesn't understand why his code wasn't working then he can read through your answer, which I've upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm debugging it now but having trouble working out what it isn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's a clue for you:

```
      previousNumber = finalArrayOfNumbers[k-0];
      if (previousNumber == finalArrayOfNumbers[k]) {
```

Clue: 'k - 0' has the same value as 'k' in the above.

Clue 2: If your intention is that `previousNumber` contains the number you are currently counting, then it needs to be initialized *outside* of the loop, and *updates* when the current number changes.

Clue 3: You should not increment `sizeOfArray` on every loop iteration ...

Based on your Question, I'd say that your thinking about / understanding of the code that you have written is *woolly*.  And this is why you are having difficulty debugging it.

In order to debug a piece of code effectively, you *first* need a mental model of how it *ought* to work.  Then you use the debugger to watch what is happening at key points to *confirm* that the program is behaving as you expect it to.

(If you come into the debugging process without a mental model, all you see is statements executing, variables changing, etcetera ... with nothing to tell you if the right thing is happening.  It is like watching the flashing lights on a computer in an old movie ... not enlightening.)

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  If it was @Nate who downvoted this, I have a bit of advice for you.  The purpose of your homework is to get you to learn how to program.  If you think you can learn to program by just asking for solutions, you are sorely mistaken.  You have to go through the thought process yourself.  You have to learn to think in code, recognize your mistakes, and correct them for yourself.  I am trying to *guide* you in that process ...

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for a hashmap where the key is the number and its value the count. This way you have a unique number and count. Your solution runs into a problem where you don't really know at index i, what count that number belongs to, unless your list has no duplicates and is in order with no gaps, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as opposed to the case of 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> occurances = new HashMap>Integer, Integer>();
int[] someSortedArray = new int[10];

//fill up a sorted array
for(int index = 0; index < someSortedArray.length; index++)
{
    someSortedArray[index] = index+1;
}

int current = someSortedArray[0];
int count = 1;
for(int index = 1; index < someSortedArray.length; index++)
{
    if(someSortedArray[index] != current)
    {
        occurances.put(current, count);
        current = someSortedArray[index];
        count = 1;
    }else
    {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println(occurances);
```

Comment: I have no duplicates thanks. I have that sorted, I just need to get the above code working, knowing what it belongs to isn't an issue.

Comment: you don't need to know which count the number belongs to? so its just a bunch of counts with no mapping?

Comment: also, the whole point is that there are duplicate numbers in the sorted array, otherwise it would just return a count of 1 for every number

Comment: Don't worry about mapping or anything, I just need to know how If I have an array of:

[20, 20, 40, 40, 50]

I can get back

[2, 2, 1]  


Thank you.

Comment: just tack on getValues() from occurrences and you get that

Comment: @Nate The answer roguequery has provided you here is far more efficient and clear than what you have - so much so that there really is no reason to try and wedge your square into the circle hole you have. The answer provides a result more than sufficient to solve the problem you have in your question and you can get the exact data you want from it with little more than a single function call.

Comment: We haven't used hashmaps yet in class, so I cannot use them.

I need a solution using my method.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it (haven't compiled).
You where not increasing sizeOfArray anywhere in your for loop.

```
// Get the count of instances.
int[] countOfNumbers = new int[50];         // Array to store count
int sizeOfArray = 0;                        // Last position of array filled
int instanceCounter = 1;                    // Counts number of instances
int previousNumber = finalArrayOfNumbers[0]; // Number stored at [k-1]

for (int k=1; k < finalArrayOfNumbers.length; k++) {
    if (previousNumber == finalArrayOfNumbers[k]) {
        instanceCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
       countOfNumbers[sizeOfArray] = instanceCounter;
       instanceCounter = 1; 
       sizeOfArray++;
       previousNumber = finalArrayOfNumbers[k]
    }
 }

 countOfNumbers[sizeOfArray] = instanceCounter;
```

Comment: Providing the OP with fixed code will NOT help him learn how to program.  He needs to work it out for himself ...

Comment: @StephenC I don't usually answer homework questions, however it did seem to me the OP was on the right track and got stuck. I believed the modifications to the OP code in my answer were minor and would enable him to tackle such problems in the future. Maybe I'm getting soft. I'll follow your example next time.